# Sidekiq run job only once

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have a question about how can you run sidekiq job only once f.e. just on the start of rails web-app. One thing I tried is to initialize redis semaphore in the config/initializer.rb and then used it in job, but it kinda didn't work. Here's the code I'm trying to get working:
**config/initializer.rb**

```
SEMAPHORE = Redis::Semaphore.new(:semaphore_name, :host => "localhost")
```

**queue_worker.rb**

```
class QueueWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform
    logger.info 'Start polling'
    unless SEMAPHORE.locked?
      logger.info 'Im here only once'
      SEMAPHORE.lock
    end
  end
end
```

**root_controller_action**

```
 QueueWorker.perform_async
```

Well another variant I don't know if it's possible to run sidekiq job in the initializer. If you can do that, there's no need in semaphore at all.
Thx for answering.

Comment: Seems to be a "XY problem". What are you trying to accomplish with that job? There may be simpler ways of doing that.

Comment: I'm trying to run a background job, that'll run from app start to app end. In internal it's gonna be a job that polls messages from queue and it's trying to poll messages all the time.

Comment: It sounds like you want a separate background process, definitely not a task for Sidekiq.

Comment: Em, so what is it for then?